# Bolding text containig parentheses and underscores

Tags: verbatim, bold

I want to bold, e.g., **Config_C2B()**. I get error messages using \textbf, so I tried wrapping the text in \verb, but that still fails.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Primary Problem}

With single braces \textbf{\verb|Config_C2B()|}

With double braces \textbf{{\verb|Config_C2B()|}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `\_` if you want to type an underscore:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
With single braces \textbf{Config\_C2B()}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way you can't use `\verb` inside the argument of another macro (and `\verb` would reset the font to non-bold tt-family anyway), so `\textbf{\verb|stuff|}` can't work.

Comment: Is there n equivalent to \verb in expl3 that is not subject to that restriction?

Comment: @shmuel no, reading in verbatim requires catcode changes, that's impossible for already tokenized (read as arguments) material. You can use `\detokenize` to get an approximation (spaces after control words might be inserted, macro parameters doubled), so `\newcommand\pseudoverb[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}`.